# What does 'the level set is bounded' exactly want to tell?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

'The level set is bounded.' occurs in many theorems and other places. I think I can understand the definition of 'level set' but I don't know what does 'it's bounded' want to tell me exactly in theorem proofing and in practice.

In general, a optimization algorithm starts from a $x_0$, then in the $k$ iteration and find a direction $d_k$, then line search find a suitable step size $\alpha_k$ such that $f(x_{k+1}) = f(x_k + \alpha_k d_k) \leq f(x_k)$, until reaches some termination criteria.

Is that 'The level set is bounded' is just used to ensure that $x_k$ won't go to infinity as $k \rightarrow \infty$ in the algorithm process ?

Comment: From what you are writing I would say yes, this ensrures a bound for the $|x_k|$. To give a definite answer you do not provide enough context.

Comment: @Thomas That's why confused me. In some books or articles, the author says 'For some function $f$ the level set is bounded.' but I can't see this conclusion in the following context any more :(

Comment: Usually, the assumption is used in the following way: you can enclose the level set in the starting point $\mathcal{L}(x_0)$ in a ball with diameter $R$. 

And then, the resulting convergence rate depends on $R$. If it wasn't bounded, $R$ could be $\infty$...

Answer (score 4):

The usual point is not really that the level set is bounded, but that it is compact. So that from the continuity of the function under consideration it follows that a minimum exists. Which fact can then be used to explore the convergence of minimizing methods.

But in the usual cases, the domain is inside a finite-dimensional space, so that bounded (and closed) is equivalent to compact.

Comment: Thanks for you information about the compactness :)